# zero vs close-to-zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods

I have to show two types of numbers next to each other in the table:

- Numbers that are close to zero, but not exactly zero,
- Numbers that are exactly zero.

How do I distinguish between these two types of numbers in the most concise manner?

One suggestion I have received is to use $0.0$ or $0.$ when referring to numbers that are arbitrary close to zero, i.e. $$0. = 0+\epsilon$$

and $0$ for exactly zero. Would that make sense?

Comment: What tools are at your disposal? Can you multiply them by $10$ (for example) and see if the value changed?

Comment: Take care that you do not run into a "ghosts of departed quantities" scenario. There is no mathematical "close to zero". In a numerical situation you may have some idea of "good enough" depending on input accuracy, number data type etc. Non-standard analysis has a notion for close-by numbers, but I'm almost sure you are not talking about that.

Comment: As long as you are clear about what your notation means, it should be okay.

Comment: My case is presentation related - I do not need to worry about multiplying the values. In my presentation I am illustrating a situation where I have a vector with some larger values, some values arbitrary close to zero, and finally, some values that are exactly zero. I am treating all values which are arbitrarily close to zero as zero in my example calculations, however, in the explanation of my work I want to keep the types of values separate.

Comment: Using $0.$ or $0.0$ is a good way to show that you mean zero to within a certain number of significant digits but it may not be clear that $0$ means exactly zero. I would just use $\epsilon$ and communicate to my audience that $0$ means exactly zero and $\epsilon$ means a measured quantity that, for all practical purposes, is zero.

Comment: So you are considering an approximation with some absolute or relative error in a vector norm with a minimal counting measure, i.e., a minimal number of non-zero entries. Is this related to compressive sensing (sparse basis representation?)?

Comment: Thank you all for replies, I will use $0.$ notation and explicitly specify what I mean in my presentation. @lutzl: the area of application is a TF-IDF score (from the domain of information retrieval).

Comment: Late to the party but I think it's a poor idea to use $0.$ to denote the values. It's symbolically too similar to $0$ and the decimal point is only a tiny difference. Using $0$ vs. $\varepsilon$ seems far better.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in @Jam. Wouldn't using $\epsilon$ indicate that all of those arbitrary small values are equal to each other? They are not supposed to be equal, just arbitrarily small.

Comment: @ArtursPolis You can use $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\ldots$